# Where to put 'where'?

Tags: mysql

I have following query:

```
select 
sites.denomination,
rooms.floor,
rooms.number,
(count(beds.id) - sum(if(beds.state<0,1,0))) as active
from rooms
join sites on rooms.site_id = sites.id
join beds on rooms.id = beds.room_id group by beds.room_id
order by
    sites.denomination,
    rooms.floor
```

Its works very well, but I want to add a selection on the site (field sites.id). i always get the error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual..."

Thanks!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: SELECT ... FROM ...[JOIN...ON...][WHERE ...]...[GROUP BY ... [HAVING ...]] [ORDER BY ...[LIMIT]]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
sites.denomination,
rooms.floor,
rooms.number,
(COUNT(beds.id) - SUM(if(beds.state<0,1,0))) AS active
FROM rooms
JOIN sites ON rooms.site_id = sites.id
JOIN beds ON rooms.id = beds.room_id 
//your WHERE should be here
GROUP BY beds.room_id
ORDER BY
    sites.denomination,
    rooms.floor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
sites.denomination,
rooms.floor,
rooms.number,
(count(beds.id) - sum(if(beds.state<0,1,0))) as active
from rooms
join sites on rooms.site_id = sites.id
join beds on rooms.id = beds.room_id 
where sites.id = ...
group by beds.room_id
order by
    sites.denomination,
    rooms.floor
```

Comment: Where needs to go BEFORE group by

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this"

```
select...
from...joins
where....
group by..
having.....
order by...
limit....
```

Refer [MYSQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) for more details.

So in your case it would be like:

```
select 
sites.denomination,
rooms.floor,
rooms.number,
(count(beds.id) - sum(if(beds.state<0,1,0))) as active
from rooms
join sites on rooms.site_id = sites.id
join beds on rooms.id = beds.room_id 
where ...........//Add your where condition here
group by beds.room_id
order by
    sites.denomination,
    rooms.floor
```

Comment: Should add `having` as well, as there is a calculated field in the SQL

Comment: I am missing the joins - he is using them in his query, it makes sense to add them

Comment: @DarkBee, AgeDeo: Added, Thanks :)

Comment: Where needs to go BEFORE group by

Comment: @PaulF:- Yes, I didnt see that `Group by` was present. Updated that! Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select 
sites.denomination,
rooms.floor,
rooms.number,
(count(beds.id) - sum(if(beds.state<0,1,0))) as active
from rooms
inner join sites on rooms.site_id = sites.id
inner join beds on rooms.id = beds.room_id 
where **instruction**
group by beds.room_id
order by
sites.denomination,
rooms.floor
```

Comment: Where needs to go BEFORE group by